# Windows 7 on latest 2017 MacBook Pros?

Tags: bootcamp

Is it possible to get Windows 7 on the latest 2017 MacBook Pros via Bootcamp?

Answer (score 2):

Nope, the new MacBooks only support Windows 10. You *may* be able to install Windows 10 and then install Windows 7 over top but it is unsupported and you may not be able to find drivers for it. Not recommended.

Comment: There's always a way!

Comment: tjj263. Back up your assertion, please. We would all like to know how.

Comment: That would be quite a task.